# pandasql int too large to convert error

Tags: python-2.7, pandasql

I have data like the example data below.  When I run the code below to get the count of distinct Product ID by prod cat, I’m getting the error below.  Pandas groupby with nunique doesn't seem to have any issues with it.  Does anyone see what the issue is?  The Product ID doesn’t seem like that large an integer.

Sample Data:

```
print data[['Product ID','prod cat']].head()



   Product ID prod cat
0     3488319        kew_31839
1     5250340         kew_6086
2     3500693        kew_30077
3     3500693        kew_30077
4     3500693        kew_30077
```

Code:

```
import pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

prod_df=pysqldf("""select count(distinct([Product ID])) as Prod_Cnt
                          ,[prod cat]
                        from data
                        group by [prod cat]
                        order by
                        count(distinct([Product ID])) desc""")

prod_df.head()
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 58))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-c1f2ccaca168> in <module>()
      4                         group by [prod cat]
      5                         order by
----> 6                         count(distinct([Product ID])) desc""")
      7 
      8 prod_df.head()

<ipython-input-12-54596a728697> in <lambda>(q)
      1 import pandasql
      2 from pandasql import sqldf
----> 3 pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.pyc in sqldf(query, env, db_uri)
    154     >>> sqldf("select avg(x) from df;", locals())
    155     """
--> 156     return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.pyc in __call__(self, query, env)
     56                     continue
     57                 self.loaded_tables.add(table_name)
---> 58                 write_table(env[table_name], table_name, conn)
     59 
     60             try:

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.pyc in write_table(df, tablename, conn)
    119                        message='The provided table name \'%s\' is not found exactly as such in the database' % tablename)
    120         to_sql(df, name=tablename, con=conn,
--> 121                index=not any(name is None for name in df.index.names))  # load index into db if all levels are named
    122 
    123 

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    469     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    470                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 471                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
    472 
    473 

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1149                          schema=schema, dtype=dtype)
   1150         table.create()
-> 1151         table.insert(chunksize)
   1152         if (not name.isdigit() and not name.islower()):
   1153             # check for potentially case sensitivity issues (GH7815)

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in insert(self, chunksize)
    664 
    665                 chunk_iter = zip(*[arr[start_i:end_i] for arr in data_list])
--> 666                 self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
    667 
    668     def _query_iterator(self, result, chunksize, columns, coerce_float=True,

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
    639     def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
    640         data = [dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
--> 641         conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
    642 
    643     def insert(self, chunksize=None):

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    943             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object)
    944         else:
--> 945             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    946 
    947     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.pyc in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    261     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    262         if self.supports_execution:
--> 263             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    264         else:
    265             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1051             compiled_sql,
   1052             distilled_params,
-> 1053             compiled_sql, distilled_params
   1054         )
   1055         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1187                 parameters,
   1188                 cursor,
-> 1189                 context)
   1190 
   1191         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1403                 )
   1404             else:
-> 1405                 util.reraise(*exc_info)
   1406 
   1407         finally:

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1157                         statement,
   1158                         parameters,
-> 1159                         context)
   1160             elif not parameters and context.no_parameters:
   1161                 if self.dialect._has_events:

/Users/sname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.pyc in do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    465 
    466     def do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 467         cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
    468 
    469     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER
```

Comment: Did you check to see if your SQL is actually valid?

Comment: @drum I've run the same query with different fields and it ran fine.  It's a pretty simple query, so I'm guessing that's not the issue.

Comment: Because `pysqldf` uses a SQLite backend, the error seems to come from the module not being able to support unsigned 64-bit integers. I would consider reporting the issue directly to the maintainer.